# While building nodejs from scratch how to enable puppeteer

Tags: node.js, node-modules, puppeteer

I downloaded the nodejs latest code from https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest-v10.x/ and built it. I got the node executable.

I am not clear how to setup puppeteer module as part of it. If I am installing nodejs, then I can install puppeteer using npm. If I am building nodejs, how to enable puppeteer module.

Or is there something wrong in my understanding as I am new nodejs.

Comment: I thought you install it with npm as well? (but you don't have npm?)

Comment: You mean after I built the nodejs, I need to install puppeteer using npm? Will this not lead to version compatibility issue? We have built nodejs of a particular version and then manual installation may bringup a different (most likely older) version.

Comment: I don't think it will cause problems. Puppeteer should work for node >=6.4.0.